# Laravel 5.4 and Intervention Image Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::image()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the Intervention Image (http://image.intervention.io/) package and using its Laravel integration. As stated in the document ion I have added the following to the service provider:

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

and added the following aliases to the facades

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

In my controller I'm doing just as the documentation states:

```
    // Create a thumbnail for the image
    $thumb = Image::make('images/' . $date . "/" . $request->file->hashName());
    $thumb->resize(320, 240);
    $thumb->save('images/' . $date . "/thumb_" . $request->file->hashName());
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
ErrorException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::image()
```

Edit:

It might be a possible conflict in class names? I also have a model called Image so I think it might have something to do with that

```
    // Save the image details to the database
    $image = new Image;
    $image->filename = $request->file->hashName();
    $image->path = 'images/' . $date;
    $image->album_id = $request->id;
    $image->save();

    // Create a thumbnail for the image
    $thumb = Image::make('images/' . $date . "/" . $request->file->hashName());
    $thumb->resize(320, 240);
    $thumb->save('images/' . $date . "/thumb_" . $request->file->hashName());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a class name conflict. You can use this:

`$thumb = \Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::make('images/' . $date . "/" . $request->file->hashName());`

and delete `use Image;` or `use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;` in your code